# Memory size exhausted (File smaller than my MEMORY_LIMIT)

Tags: php, file, memory, file-get-contents, readfile

I'm stuck with an annoying problem which is the title of this topic. I'm trying to read a MP4 format file (which is 69,5 MB(s). A total of 72 899 060 byte(s)) but keep receiving this error. Before reading this file i'm requesting the current usage of the memory with the function [memory_get_usage()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php). Mentioning there is only 3 MB used of a total scale of 128 MB (which is my memory_limit in PHP.ini).

This is the exact error message i'm currently receiving:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72900608 bytes)
```

The function used in order to 'read' this file is [file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php), which simply just retrieves the content of the given path / file.

Sample of the code / 'function':

```
echo memory_get_usage() . "<br/>";
$tmpItem = 'mypath/tofile/myfile.mp4';

echo file_get_contents($tmpItem);
echo memory_get_usage() . "<br/>";
```

I don't understand how we went up from using 3 MB to needing eventually 198 MB. Any ideas?

- Additional: I've also tried fopen(), fread(), fclose & readfile(). All having the same effect mentioned above sadly.

Comment: you are trying to echo the file with : file_get_contents , it's obvious that it will result to memory size exhausted. as this is not how you play a video file

Comment: I'm not trying to play a video file. I'm trying to fetch its content.

Comment: Whatever , you should not echo it , just write it into a file.

Comment: @ArshSingh I want the file its content eventually zipped into a zip file. So that's why i'm trying to fetch the files content.

Comment: If you are concerned about memory exhausted then you should not echo it ,,,, you question was about that.

Comment: @ArshSingh please explain your comment. It's NOT obvious. (btw, buffered output can be flushed)

Comment: @ArshSingh What's the difference of assigning the content to a variable / echoing the content? None. Right?

Comment: @Testuser075 echo tents to read the text , which is inside the file , it takes a lot of time for the server to output you the content of that file , as it's not a normal text file, doing echo of normal array or text takes way less time that echoing the file content. thats what my concern is about.

Comment: @ArshSingh Assigning it to a variable first and then echoing out the variable its value will result the same. Just tested it out.

Comment: @Testuser075 by results same you mean memory exhausted or it echo's the text

Comment: @ArshSingh Memory exhaustion

Comment: @Testuser075  it does not change anything . assign it to a variable or echo it without it , i told you that , if you tent you print the content of `file` which is not a text file obviously , it will take a lot of time to the server to print the text for you . it will result to Mmeory exhaustion .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115539/discussion-between-testuser075-and-arsh-singh).

Answer (score 1):

By `file_get_contents($tmpItem);` you get more than `mypath/tofile/myfile.mp4` equivalent size memory allocated(How can you "get file content" without loading it to the memory?!), which is enough to explain the up-going of the memory.

Answer (score 0):

PHP will allocated more memory than it actually uses. Upon trying to allocate more, it fails. Try `memory_get_usage(true);` to get to see the allocated (*reserved*) memory instead of the actually used memory.

If you want to work with the contents of the file, you gonna need way more memory, like a few gigabytes probably.

If you simply want to zip the video, you can do this by system calls without using any memory (assuming GNU Linux + zip installed):

```
<?php
exec('zip -v', $output, $zipFound);

if ($zipFound > 0) {
    throw new \Exception('Error accessing `zip` from command line, is it installed?');
}

exec('zip -q ' . $outputZip . ' ' . $inputMp4, $output, $zipError);

if ($zipError !== 0) {
    throw new \Exception('Error while compressing files: ' . $output);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. On servers calls, is there any in-built 'software' to pack files into zips / tars? And how about if I retrieve my content using fread (including chunks) and flush my output buffer after each chunk. Would that be possible too?

Comment: @Testuser075 software to pack files into zips? Well I showed you one in the example didn't I ? Loading chunks would also work but it's still not neccesary. Even if you use PHP's `\ZipArchive` class, it's overhead which you don't need.

Comment: Your method requires a lot of RAM. That's why I was curious about if mine should work. Can't get it to work tbh.

Comment: Of course it takes some RAM to compress a file... why you don't get it to work? What errors?